Found hard white plasticky surface just behind dry wall
While drilling a hole to fit a mirror, I found this hard surface just behind the drywall (12mm into the hole, so right after the drywall).
Knocking on the drywall, that area sounds full, but on three sides around it, it sounds hollow, so I'm fairly confused. Do you have any idea what it might be?
It's a detached house in England, built in 1999.
This is located at the entrance to the downstairs cloak room, above the sink. It's the left hole in the picture. The right was all fine. On the other side of the wall, it's the living room, and there's nothing special on the wall there.



Maybe PVC plumbing vent pipe for the sink ... ?
